# Как убрать ссылки с форума на движке punBB?

Tags: php

Как запретить внешние ссылки на форуме punbb?

Хочу запретить публиковать ссылки на моем форуме, который работает на движке punbb. Хочу запретить публиковать ссылки на внешние сайты и ссылки в подписи и в профиле пользователей.

Как это сделать?

Comment: @meravaz, проверяйте входные данные регулярками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое решение есть, если верить автору, то в его моде можно отключить ссылки вообще. [fancy spam stop](http://punbb.ru/topic4154-reliz-fancy-stop-spam.html)
А вообще я бы покопался с настройками `bbcode`...